# Getting the return value of functions passed in as variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I am currently trying to write a function which takes as its parameters two truth functions and returns a boolean based on whether or not they are  logically equivalent. For example, let say the main function is

```
def logical_equiv(function1, function2):
    #function1 and function2 are truth functions
```

I have done a check to see if the two functions passed in are the same by doing

```
def logical_equiv(function1, function2):
    if function1 == function2:
         return True
```

But how do I check the actual return value of function1 and function2? To be clearer, let say function1 takes two parameters P and Q, then returned (not P) or (not Q) and function2 also takes two parameters P and Q then returned not(P and Q), how would i check that in my logical_equiv function? I tried doing

```
def logical_equiv(function1, function2):
     if function1 == (not P) or (not Q):
          #do something
```

But this returns the error`NameError: name 'P' is not defined`
Printing out the function from logical_equiv returns a memory address.

Comment: Show us the 'real' code and the errors you get. You cannot say `if function1 == function2:` because you are comparing object references so that will usually be false. You need to look at the number of arguments of the functions and they must be the same all the time. Then you need to construct a truth table (ie an array of boolean values of the input and an expected output) then call each function with the set of boolean values and compare they both return the same boolean value.

Comment: I agree with @dopstar... it's hard to see why you'd want to see the internal code of `function1` and `function2`, so editing your post to include your specific problem will help. I know SO is all about generalization but in this case we need to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see if they are logically equivalent using the same arguments:

```
def logical_equiv(function1, function2, *args):
    return function1(*args) == function2(*args)
```

Then:

```
>>> func1 = lambda P, Q: (not P) or (not Q)
>>> func2 = lambda P, Q: not(P and Q)
>>> logical_equiv(func1, func2, True, False)
True
```

This could be extended to any number of arguments:

```
>>> func1 = lambda P, Q, R: (not P) or (not Q) or (not R)
>>> func2 = lambda P, Q, R: not(P and Q and R)
>>> logical_equiv(func1, func2, True, False, True)
True
```

If you need to test all valid combinations of `[True, False]` for `n` parameters, then you can do:

```
from itertools import product
def logical_equiv(f1, f2):
    n = f1.__code__.co_argcount        # @dopstart
    if n != f2.__code__.co_argcount:
        return False
    return all(f1(*args) == f2(*args) for args in product([True, False], repeat=n))

>>> func1 = lambda P, Q, R: (not P) or (not Q) or (not R)
>>> func2 = lambda P, Q, R: not(P and Q and R)
>>> logical_equiv(func1, func2)
True
```

Comment: The whole idea of logical equivalence is making me nervous. Maybe this is what the OP wanted but. If function1 is a straight line function `y = x` and function2 `y = x^3` is a cubic function and you call `logical_equiv(func1, func2, 0)` or `logical_equiv(func1, func2, 1)` or even `logical_equiv(func1, func2, -1)`, one will think the two function are logically equivalent if he used those intersection points but they are not.

Comment: Agree, maybe the OP intends to test all valid inputs, which is achievable with a logical function of `n` parameters `itertools.product([True, False], n)`  but not for continuous functions.

Comment: Lets say function1 returns the python equivalent of ~P ∨ ~Q which of course would be just `return (not P) or (not Q)` and function2 returns ~(P and Q) which would be `return not(P and Q)`.  Python already knows these are both equal, but in my function to check this, I cant just do if function1 == function2. I wasn't able figure out the syntax.

Comment: How does Python know they are equivalent? `function1 == function2` just checks that the identity of function1 is the same as the identity of function2, which is only be true if they are the same function, i.e. `logical_equiv(func1, func1) -> True`. You need to call these functions, e.g. `function1()` and pass in the arguments, which is what the code above shows. If this isn't what you are looking for can you please update the question and provide more specific details.

Comment: And now im no longer nervous about your logical equivalence function. Great stuff. You beat me to the truth table construction via `itertools.product`, I wont post my answer. However you can make `logical_equiv` to detect the number of args the functions take (which is `f1.__code__.co_argcount`, if they are not the same, then `False` is returned because they are not equivalent. Then that argcount is used to feed `repeat` param of `itertools.product` so that you just say `logical_equiv(func1, func2)`.

Comment: Great idea to test arg count, will update, to remove `n` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to do:

```
def logical_equiv(function1, function2):
     if function1() in [(not P), (not Q)]:
          #do something
```

Of course, you need to define `P` and `Q`. Remember, `function1` is just a reference to the function, whereas `function1()` calls the function, returning its value.

Additionally, to check if the output of `function1` and `function2` are equivalent, just do:

```
if function1() == function2():
    ...
```

Comment: what if the functions take N arguments?

Comment: But function1 and function2 also take paramters?

Comment: If they *take* multiple parameters, just change the function calls to something like: `function1(a, b)`. Do you mean if they `return` multiple values as well?

Comment: I mean arguments as `function1(a, b, c, d, ...)` like you mentioned. But, mathematically, I dont think its sufficient to conclude the functions are equivalent just because they "intersect" at some particular input parameter set. In such a way the code must build a truth table and call both functions `2^N`. In the cause of only 2 arguments `a` and `b`, the functions must be compared for all the `2^2 = 4` scenarios.

Comment: Ahh, no, you're correct there. I misread this as only checking for a single parameter set.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it based on @WillHall comment but its not general enough to answer the general question. I declared two string variables `P ="P"` and `Q="Q" ` then did `if function1(P,Q) == function2(P,Q):               return True`